# Can't figure out how to calculate maximum likelihood estimate for prior in the following example

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I am working on the Berkeley AI materials by myself [here](http://ai.berkeley.edu/home.html) and I can't figure out the following example from one of the autograded homeworks there. Here is a screenshot of the problem below:

[image]

Here is my answer below:

[image]

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong, as I thought this was the number of labels of certain value divided by the total number of data instances. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be a stupid comment, but have you tried reducing this to the lowest fraction, i.e. 2/3 and 1/5?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried everything. I think it must be an error with the site, but I was confused because I figured I was doing something incorrect. I can this can marked as resolved.